# Oracle - pl sql selecting from SYS_REFCURSOR

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a function that returns a SYS_REFCURSOR that has a single row but multiple columns. What I'm looking to do is to be able to have a SQL query that has nested sub-queries using the column values returned in the SYS_REFCURSOR. Alternative ideas such as types, etc would be appreciated. Code below is me writing on-the-fly and hasn't been validated for syntax.

```
--Oracle function
CREATE DummyFunction(dummyValue AS NUMBER) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
  RETURN_DATA SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN RETURN_DATA
  SELECT
    TO_CHAR(dummyValue) || 'A' AS ColumnA
    ,TO_CHAR(dummyValue) || 'B' AS ColumnB
  FROM
    DUAL;

  RETURN RETURN_DATA;
END;

--sample query with sub-queries; does not work
SELECT
  SELECT ColumnA FROM DummyFunction(1) FROM DUAL AS ColumnA
  ,SELECT ColumnB FROM DummyFunction(1) FROM DUAL AS ColumnB
FROM
  DUAL;
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059299/table-valued-functions-in-oracle-11g-parameterized-views

Answer (score 5):

A SYS_REFCURSOR won't work for the intended use - you need to create an Oracle TYPE:

```
CREATE TYPE your_type IS OBJECT (
  ColumnA VARCHAR2(100),
  ColumnB VARCHAR2(100)
)
```

Update your function:

```
CREATE DummyFunction(dummyValue AS NUMBER) 
RETURN your_type
IS

BEGIN

  INSERT INTO your_type
  SELECT TO_CHAR(dummyValue) || 'A' AS ColumnA,
         TO_CHAR(dummyValue) || 'B' AS ColumnB
    FROM DUAL;

  RETURN your_type;

END;
```

Then you can use:

```
SELECT (SELECT ColumnA FROM table(DummyFunction(1))) AS ColumnA, 
       (SELECT ColumnB FROM table(DummyFunction(1))) AS ColumnB
  FROM DUAL
```

The example is overcomplicated - all you need to use is:

```
SELECT x.columna,
       x.columnb
  FROM table(DummyFunction(1)) x
```