# table value function syntax error

Tags: oracle

i have the following code for table value Function in oracle 12c on windows8
as following

```
 CREATE TABLE MisJob
   ( ID RAW(16), 
 JobTitle VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
 MinSalary NUMBER(6,0), 
 MaxSalary NUMBER(6,0),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
 )


CREATE TYPE MISJOBType AS OBJECT ( JobTitle VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), MinSalary NUMBER(6,0),MaxSalary NUMBER(6,0));

CREATE TYPE MISJOBTypeCol AS TABLE OF MISJOBType;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fEmployee (jobid IN RAW(16))
RETURN MISJOBTypeCol PIPELINED IS
BEGIN 
  FOR i IN (SELECT *  FROM MisJob)LOOP
  PIPE ROW(MISJOBType(i.JobTitle, i.MinSalary,i.MaxSalary));
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
```

but i am getting the error 
Error(2,13): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:     := . ) , @ % default character The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.

and i don't know why even though i have followed this example 
[Table-Valued Functions in ORACLE 11g ? ( parameterized views )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059299/table-valued-functions-in-oracle-11g-parameterized-views)

what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the size constraint on the formal argument:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fEmployee (jobid IN RAW)
...
```

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS657):

> ... you cannot include a constraint in a formal parameter declaration